# phpでのseleniumを使ったスクレイピングについて

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, web-scraping

[【Webブラウザの自動操作を使って、単純作業を効率化】Seleniumの実装方法について](https://www.genius-web.co.jp/blog/cat-119/selenium_+implementation.html)

上記サイトを参考に以下コードで実行いたしましたが、

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.
```

というエラーが発生しております。

Seleniumの仕組みをいまいちわかっていないこともあり、原因が思いつかないのですがわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**

OS：CentOS７
ブラウザ：GoogleChrome(ver75.0.3770.90)
インストールしたもの
　・PHP 7.1.30
　・GoogleChrome(ver75.0.3770.90)
　・chromedriver(75.0.3770.90)
　・Selenium-server
　・php-webdriver

以下のtest.phpはドキュメントルートにあり、インストールした各ツールは`/usr/local/bin`配下にあります。

**実行したコード** (test.php)

```
<?php require '/usr/local/bin/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;

$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(['--headless']);
$host = 'http://localhost:80';
$capabilities = Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
$driver = Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
$driver->get('https://www.google.co.jp/');
$browserLogs = $driver->manage()->getLog('browser');
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('q'));
$element->sendKeys('php スクレイピング');
$element->submit();
$driver->wait(15)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('php　スクレイピング - Google 検索')
);
if ($driver->getTitle() !== 'php　スクレイピング - Google 検索') {
    throw new Exception('fail');
}
$file = "サンプル_chrome.png";
$driver->takeScreenshot($file);
$driver->close();
```

**実行時のエラーメッセージ**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4
The response: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /session was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>'
 in /usr/local/bin/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:298
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(126): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand))
#1 /var/www/html/test.php(14): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php on line 298
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/195269